# Events of DataTemplate don't work when it is loaded from outside of the page

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

If I add my DataTemplate from *StandardStyles.xaml* then the button event doesn't work. Here is my code:

*StandardStyles.xaml*

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TestTemplate">
    <Button x:Name="TestButton" Width="32" Height="32" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

*MyPage.xaml*

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}">
</FlipView>
```

*MyPage.xaml.cs*

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("EVENT WORKS!!");
}
```

If I click on the button nothing happens. All styles are loading correctly qua layout. When I add the template inside *MyPage.xaml* as page resource or directly inside the FlipView control then it works fine. For example, this works:

```
<!-- MyPage.xaml -->
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" >
  <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="TestTemplate">
      <Button x:Name="TestButton" Width="32" Height="32" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Why is the event doesn't work when the template is loaded from outside of the page?